# Shredding XML into an SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a few "given" things:

- An SQL Server 2012 table with certain structure
- Data provided as `XML` with certain structure

My code has to shred that XML into a row in the table. I'm looking to get feedback on how I'm getting the data for each column from the XML variable.

Here's a realistic yet minimal repro of my scenario:

```sql
-- Table structure is "a given", i.e. I *have to* work with this:
CREATE TABLE #Person 
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    First_Name NVARCHAR(100), 
    Last_Name NVARCHAR(100), 
    Two_Char_Nationality VARCHAR(2),
    InsertedAt DATETIME -- My code has to manually insert the timestamp here (cannot create a default constraint)
);

-- Xml structure is "a given", i.e. I *have to* work with this:
DECLARE @data XML = '<Person>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <Surname>Doe</Surname>
  <Nationality>
    <Fullname>Netherlands</Fullname>
    <IsoAlpha2>NL</IsoAlpha2>
  </Nationality>
</Person>';

-- Looking to get feedback on this:
INSERT INTO #Person
(
    First_Name,
    Last_Name, 
    Two_Char_Nationality,
    InsertedAt
)
VALUES
(
    (SELECT @data.value('(/Person/FirstName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')),
    (SELECT @data.value('(/Person/Surname)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)')),
    (SELECT @data.value('(/Person/Nationality/IsoAlpha2)[1]', 'VARCHAR(2)')),
    GETDATE()
);

-- For testing purposes only:
SELECT * FROM #Person
DROP TABLE #Person
```

As you can see I'm doing many sub-select-queries in the `VALUES(...)` part, which doesn't feel all too smart.

In reality, there's about 10 - 20 columns in my `#Person` table, and sometimes my XML is *slightly* more nested, but I'm trying to focus on the basics first.

Any recommendations on the `INSERT` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO #Person
(
    First_Name,
    Last_Name, 
    Two_Char_Nationality,
    InsertedAt
)
SELECT
    tab.p.value('FirstName[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    tab.p.value('Surname[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'),
    tab.p.value('(Nationality/IsoAlpha2)[1]', 'VARCHAR(2)'),
    GETDATE()
FROM
    @data.nodes('/Person') tab(p);
```

[SELECT or Query nodes in hierarchial or nested XML](http://sqlwithmanoj.com/2011/07/13/select-or-query-nodes-in-hierarchial-or-nested-xml/)